# How to solve "access_denied" in AngelList API

Tags: api

I'm trying to call AngelList API by the following url to [GET all startups](https://market.mashape.com/community/angellist#get-startups-filter-raising):

https://api.angel.co/1/startups/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&accept=text/plain

I got the message:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This access token is invalid or has been revoked by the user."}
```

I tried to put the "default application key" and another key that I generated. but I'm facing the same problem.

1- Does anybody know how I should get companies in angellist in the right way?

p.s: I'm facing the same problem for getting a company by id as well.